# How to find second largest number using Scanner and for loop(no array)

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner

So I can easily accomplish task to find largest number and then if can be divided by three, print out. But do not know how to find second largest number from users sequence.
Thanks for any hints!

```
public class SecondLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers?");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Write numbers: ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int c = scan.nextInt();
            if(c>=max && c%3 == 0){
                max = c;
                }
            else
                System.out.println("There is no such number.");



        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code and your comment don't match.  Are you looking for (the largest number divisible by 3), which is what your code currently does, or are you looking for (the largest number), then when the program is done, determining whether it's divisible by three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int secondLargest = 0;
.....
for (..) {
   ....
   if (c % 3 == 0) {
       if (c >= max) {
           secondLargest = max;
           max = c;
       }
       if (c >= secondLargest && c < max) {
           secondLargest = c;
       }
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its not homework. I'm just training random stuff to be more fluent.

Comment: When you update max, you'll also want to update secondLargest.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep 2 variables, one for maximum and another for second_maximum and update them appropriately.

For a more general approach, take a look at [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code will work

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practical4 {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int max = 0, second_max = 0, temp, numbers;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        numbers = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                max = scanner.nextInt();
            } else {
                temp = scanner.nextInt();
                if (temp > max) {
                    second_max = max;
                    max = temp;
                }
                else if(temp>second_max)
                {
                 second_max=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("Second max number is :" + second_max);
    }
}
```